# How to perform a left inner join or similar operation using VBA and MS-ACCESS to join based on shared ID key in four excel sheets?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, join, ms-access-2010

I have an ms-access button that I use to grab a specific excel file and behind that button is a vba script. I treat the file like an object. This excel file has 9 sheets. Only 2,3,4,5 I am concerned with. I don't want to alter the original 2nd sheet, what I'd like to do is create a copy of the 2nd sheet and place that at the end of the excel sheet (temporarily). This is so I can access that merged sheet and run a set of data validations against it. Once those validations are complete I can remove it, so it's as if the file was never altered.

I want to perform a left inner join or sth like it so that sheet 2 is joined with all columns from 3,4,5, based on the shared join key "Unique Transaction ID", even if there is not a match with the columns they should still be added. And if a match is found with the key, then that rows data is added to the correct line and corresponding column.

The sheets are set up like this:

Sheet 2:

| A |  |
| --- | --- |
| **Unique Transaction ID** | **some_header** |
| 321 | d1 |
| 123 | d2 |
| 333 | d3 |
| 231 | d4 |
| 908 | d5 |
| 111 | d6 |
| 367 | d7 |

Sheet 3:

| A |  |
| --- | --- |
| **Unique Transaction ID** | **another_header** |
| 333 | q |
| 231 | w |
| 908 | e |

Sheet 4:

| A |  |
| --- | --- |
| **Unique Transaction ID** | **x_header** |
| 321 | h |
| 123 | t |

Sheet 5:

| A |  |
| --- | --- |
| **Unique Transaction ID** | **z_header** |
| 321 |  |
| 123 |  |
| 333 |  |
| 231 |  |
| 908 |  |
| 111 | b_2 |
| 367 | a_1 |

The ranges for each sheet is:

```
Sheet 2: A to AU
Sheet 3: A to I
Sheet 4: A to H
Sheet 5: A to D`
```

Since I only need the A column "Unique Transaction ID" from Sheet 2, the other ranges would start at "B" I think.

And the merged sheet should therefore be the range: A to BM

When horizontally merged the ranges for the sheets would be:

```
Sheet 2: A to AU
Sheet 3: AV to BC
Sheet 4: BD to BJ
Sheet 5: BK to BM
```

The result of the merge should produce a sheet that looks like this:

```
A
Unique Transaction ID | some_header | another_header | x_header | z_header | 
321                   | d1          |                | h        |          |
123                   | d2          |                | t        |          |
333                   | d3          | q              |          |          |
231                   | d4          | w              |          |          |
908                   | d5          | e              |          |          |
111                   | d6          |                |          | b_2      |
367                   | d7          |                |          | a_1      |
```

And of course there will be many columns in between those columns.

Is there an error in my reasoning? A more straight-forward approach?

Any help appreicated
Thank you

Here is what Ive tried, none seems to fully do the merge correctly. I can get to the point where I have a copy of sheet 2 and all its columns/data but nothing from sheet 3,4,5.

Example:

```
    `Public Sub Init(filePath As Variant)
        ' Connect to original file
        Dim xlApp As Excel.Application, objFile As Excel.Workbook
        Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        Set objFile = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath)
        
        ' Get the number of sheets
        numSheets = objFile.Worksheets.Count
        
        If numSheets = 9 Then
            ' Define variables for Sheet 2 and the other sheets
            Dim sht2 As Worksheet, sht3 As Worksheet, sht4 As Worksheet, sht5 As Worksheet
            Dim lastCol As Long, copyRange As Range, pasteRange As Range
            
            ' Set variables to the correct worksheets
            Set sht2 = objFile.Worksheets("Sheet2")
            Set sht3 = objFile.Worksheets("Sheet3")
            Set sht4 = objFile.Worksheets("Sheet4")
            Set sht5 = objFile.Worksheets("Sheet5")
            
            ' Get the last column in Sheet 2
            lastCol = sht2.Cells(1, sht2.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            
            ' Loop through each column in Sheet 3, 4, and 5 and paste the values into Sheet 2
            For i = 1 To lastCol
                ' Set the copy and paste ranges for each column
                Set copyRange = Union(sht3.Cells(1, i), sht4.Cells(1, i), sht5.Cells(1, i)).EntireColumn
                Set pasteRange = sht2.Cells(1, sht2.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1)
                ' Copy and paste the values
                pasteRange.Resize(copyRange.Rows.Count, copyRange.Columns.Count).Value = copyRange.Value
            Next i
        End If
        
        ' Close the original file and clean up
        objFile.Close SaveChanges:=False
        xlApp.Quit
        Set objFile = Nothing
        Set xlApp = Nothing
    End Sub`
```

I tried this, but cant use the Union feature in vba.

This one adds everything from sheet 2, but columns/data from sheet 3,4,5 are not there:

```
' Initialize object and set default values
Public Sub Init(filePath As Variant)
    
    ' Connect to original file
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application, objFile As Excel.Workbook
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set objFile = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath)
    
    ' Get the number of sheets
    numSheets = objFile.Worksheets.Count
    
    If numSheets = 9 Then
        ' Get references to the relevant sheets
        Dim sheet2 As Excel.Worksheet, sheet3 As Excel.Worksheet, sheet4 As Excel.Worksheet, sheet5 As Excel.Worksheet
        Set sheet2 = objFile.Worksheets("sheet2")
        Set sheet3 = objFile.Worksheets("sheet3")
        Set sheet4 = objFile.Worksheets("sheet4")
        Set sheet5 = objFile.Worksheets("sheet5")
        
        ' Make a copy of sheet 2 and set it as the active sheet
        sheet2.Copy After:=objFile.Worksheets(numSheets)
        Dim mergedSheet As Excel.Worksheet
        Set mergedSheet = objFile.Worksheets(numSheets + 1)
        mergedSheet.Activate
        
        ' Add a header row to the merged sheet
        Dim headerRange As Excel.Range
        Set headerRange = Range("A1:AU1")
        headerRange.Copy
        Range("AV1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Range("BD1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Range("BK1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        
        ' Loop through the unique transaction IDs in sheet 2 and find matching rows in sheets 3, 4, and 5
        Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
        lastRow = sheet2.Cells(sheet2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To lastRow ' Start at row 2 to skip the header row
            
            ' Get the unique transaction ID from sheet 2
            Dim uniqueID As String
            uniqueID = sheet2.Cells(i, "A").Value
            
            ' Find matching row in sheet 3 and copy values to merged sheet
            Dim matchRange As Excel.Range
            Set matchRange = sheet3.Columns("A").Find(uniqueID)
            If Not matchRange Is Nothing Then
                matchRange.Resize(1, 8).Copy
                mergedSheet.Cells(i, "AV").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End If
            
            ' Find matching row in sheet 4 and copy values to merged sheet
            Set matchRange = sheet4.Columns("A").Find(uniqueID)
            If Not matchRange Is Nothing Then
                matchRange.Resize(1, 7).Copy
                mergedSheet.Cells(i, "BD").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End If
            
            ' Find matching row in sheet 5 and copy values to merged sheet
            Set matchRange = sheet5.Columns("A").Find(uniqueID)
            If Not matchRange Is Nothing Then
                matchRange.Resize(1, 3).Copy
                mergedSheet.Cells(i, "BK").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End If
        Next i
        
        ' Auto-fit the columns in the merged sheet and save the file
        mergedSheet.Columns.AutoFit
        objFile.Save
    End If
    
    ' Close the file and quit Excel
    objFile.Close SaveChanges:=True
    xlApp.Quit`
```

Comment: Can build a query that joins sheets and use CopyFromRecordset to save that dataset to another sheet. Why not have Access set links to worksheets then work with those linked tables?

Comment: @June7 havent worked with linked tables. Above is the way I understand how to work with the data. Can you explain more about CopyFromRecordset and how they would be applied here. Is there anything wrong with the above code. It appears to work in a way, it creates a copy of the second sheet and places it at the end but none of the left inner join type logic executes.

Comment: "*And of course there will be many columns in between those columns.*" - why do you say 'of course' - nothing in your example data would indicate that. Exactly which columns do you want to pull from? If the fields you show are not adjacent, then building a recordset with JOINs will not be practical. Suggest you do research on CopyFromRecordset to learn if it could be applicable to your situation. If sheets are a simple structure, linking from Access should be simple. Have you even tried?

Comment: @June7 many columns in between meaning, the ranges are Sheet 2: A to AU, Sheet 3: AV to BC, Sheet 4: BD to BJ, Sheet 5: BK to BM. The columns shown were just for demonstration.

Comment: Yes, I see that now in the narrative. That is a lot of columns. You also show that sheet2 has 1-to-1 relationship with each of the other sheets. Is that accurate? I've never seen nor used UNION() function. Will have to do some testing.

Comment: @June7 Not exactly 1-to-1 if I understand the meaning correct. I incorrectly wrote sheet 5. Actually sheet 5 has all the same ID's as sheet 1. So IDs of sheet 5 will always be exactly what is shown in sheet 1, they are mapped to each other in excel.

Comment: You don't show a sheet 1 so how is it relevant? By 1-to-1 I mean the ID values are unique in each sheet and sheet 2 will have all ID values.

Comment: @June7 I investigated the CopyFromRecordset and linked tables. Unfortunately these two approached are too manual from what I understand, I am working with hundreds of excel files.

Comment: @June7 Apologies, I meant to say sheet 2, not sheet 1. Sheet 1 is irrelevant. Each sheet contains some combination of the ID's in sheet 2, not all of them. Only sheet 2 and sheet 5 have all the IDs.

Comment: Whether or not other methods could be used for your 'hundreds' of files depends on their structure and your work process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First procedure will not compile. It triggers 'Method or data member not found.' error for `copyRange.Value`. Second procedure works. Data is copied but column headers are just Sheet 2 repeated. If you want headers from other sheets, then reference each sheet header and copy before each paste. However, select/copy/paste is not necessary. Consider:

```
        ' Add a header row to the merged sheet
        Range("AV1:BC1").Value = sheet3.Range("A1:I1").Value
        Range("BD1:BJ1").Value = sheet4.Range("A1:H1").Value
        Range("BK1:BM1").Value = sheet5.Range("A1:D1").Value
```